# How to pass in 128 bit sequence as input in an OCaml program?

Tags: encryption, ocaml

i'm writing an ocaml program, and i need to pass in a 128 bit sequence and output a 128 bit sequence. what should be the type of my input/output in my module signature?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Zarith](http://opam.ocaml.org/packages/zarith/zarith.1.2/) library if your sequence is a number. If it is just a sequence of bits, then you can just use `string`. Potentially, you can use [Bitstring](http://opam.ocaml.org/packages/bitstring/bitstring.2.0.4/) library if you need some complex processing. If you're still not sure then use `string`.